# To publish a custom event and asynchronously handle it in Spring MVC based Rest application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, concurrency

I have written a Rest application based on Spring MVC wherein I am required to do some validations, some of the validations are Hard rules and some of them are Soft rules. Soft rules if they fail generate a warning, but if the hard rules fail they generate an error.
First I am checking the hard rules if any fail then, at that time only, I am returning back the response, but let the process continue to process the subsequent Soft rules.

Herein I would like to know how to create two parallel threads in Spring to do this?
OR How to publish a custom event and asynchronously handle it in another thread and let the original thread continue its work in Spring?

I know about @async and SpringTaskExecutor, but how to best use them here.

I am seeking design and architectural guidelines and ideas to handle this task in best possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned soft rule(s) validation failure only generates warning it can be handled in a separate background process. This way main thread can focus solely on hard rule(s) without bothering itself about soft rule(s).

For above behavior below points need to be implemented

- For every request persist the relevant data, for soft rule processing, with flag `processed=false` and preferably time stamp (*for insertion and processed*).
- Post persisting the data, let the main thread continue with hard rule processing.
- Introduce a scheduled service (via [`@Scheduled`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html)) which will periodically fetch the unprocessed data and mark them as `processed=true` post soft rule processing along with relevant processed time stamp. (*This will as act as the background process which will periodically poll the data for unprocessed rule(s)*)

Do ensure that the respective transactions viz. soft rule data insertion and processing are well isolated. Also the error handling should be robust in terms of system failures when rule processing are in progress.

Let know in comments if more information is required.

Comment: Please elaborate this in some more detail!! I mean what constructs I should be using,  or rather should I  be using Async to fork new threads, Which is the preferred way to start background process in Spring

Comment: @JohnDoe No need for `@Async` or forking new threads as the main thread will validate hard rule **only** and soft rule validation will be done by background process.

Comment: Also as mentioned in post use `@Scheduled` for background process. See [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-enable-annotation-support) for samples.